# Multi-Relational Learning via Tensor Factorization

Tags: machine-learning, multivariate-analysis, graph-theory, matrix-decomposition

Multi-relational data expressed in terms of a 3 order tensor, has been used to perform statistical relational learning (SRL) on heterogeneous networks using tensor factorization (eg. [RESCAL](http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~nickel/data/paper-icml2011.pdf)). The tensor representation can be expressed as $N \times N \times R$, where $N$ is the set of nodes in the graph, and $R$ is the set of relations present in the network.

However, matrix factorization directly on adjacency matrices corresponding to a homogeneous graph is something unheard of. Usually, any subspace learning is applied on the kernelized adjcancy matrix.

So, my main question is: What makes tensor factorization a viable option for performing SRL on multi-relational data, but matrix factorization not for an adjacency matrix of a graph?

When dealing with multi-relation graphs, what are the alternatives to tensor factoriaztion for performing SRL? Any deep methods?

Comment: What does SRL mean?

Comment: @DavidJ.Harris Statistical Relational Learning, tasks such as collective classification or link prediction. 

I edited the original question to include the origins of the abbreviations.